# Apache not allowing external traffic

Tags: apache-http-server, webserver

I have set up a home server to serve files, and I have Apache running on one computer(listening on port 82) with the router set to redirect all requests on port 82 to the local IP of my webserver.  I can access my web files by using localhost:82 and 192.168.1.145(my webserver's local IP), but when using the external IP, the connection just times out.  I know that my router is redirecting fine because it will send port 82 requests to my laptop if I change the redirect address.

I have:

- Apache 2.2.22
- Linksys E2500 Router

I have done:

- Set port redirect on my router to 82 and 192.168.1.145
- Turned on Apache to listen on port 82(non-specific)

Just one question: why won't Apache accept external traffic?

Here is my httpd.conf: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1LBSk2Z8CR79dD--yhcwke2hEa_ZBPU8OZD1Eddohz64/edit?pli=1 (sorry it's a Google Doc) - the ServerAdmin and ServerName fields have been changed for privacy

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**FIXED:**  My computer's firewall was blocking only external traffic(not internal) and I created an exception which fixed the problem.